# svg and javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am new to javascript and I want to implement a pulley in which I need to draw a circle using SVG to which 2 strings are attached touching to its circumference at diameter. Also I want to show 2 rectangular blocks attached to these strings at the end which will have 2 weights *w1* an *w2*. Taking *w1* and *w2* as inputs from the user, I need to calculate the tension on the string as *T1 = w1*g*. Also if *w1 > w2* block will move downwards along with the string. How can I implement it using SVG and Javascript?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What part of this are you having trouble with? Do you know how to create an SVG document, or embed SVG in XHTML? Do you know how to draw circles and lines and boxes with SVG? Do you know how to add JavaScript to your SVG? Do you know how to use JavaScript to manipulate properties of objects? Edit your question to show us what you have done so far, and what you need help with, and we'll be happy to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/) which I quote:

> Raphaël is a small JavaScript library that should simplify your work with vector graphics on the web.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: i know how to draw images in SVG but don't know how to add animation. Like if i click on a button, two blocks should move in opposite direction.

Comment: @tester You have marked this answer as "accepted", but it seems that it did not answer your needs. If you have further questions, you should edit your question above with more details, or ask further (specific) followup questions.