# how to draw a pulley in svg?

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to draw a pulley shown under "Standard Pulley Problem" title at http://www.sparknotes.com/testprep/books/sat2/physics/chapter8section2.rhtml in svg and want to take values for m and M from user using javascript. how can i do that?

Comment: Try building with http://raphaeljs.com/. Just look at those awesome examples!

Comment: Why is this not a duplicate of [the question you asked 6 days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528350/svg-and-javascript) and did not provide any additional details upon when asked?

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com) since it works in every browser and  it has an awesome API. You could even make it interactive, so that the user can drag "F" with their mouse to lift "m".

Comment: <html> <head> <title>Raphael</title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
         <style type="text/css">
             #canvas_container {
                 width: 500px;
                 border: 1px solid #aaa;
             }
     window.onload = function()
  {
     var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);
     var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 80);
     circle.attr("stroke", "#f1f1f1");
  circle.attr("stroke-width", 2);

  }
         </style>
     </head>
     <body> <div id="canvas_container"></div>
     </body> </html>

Comment: The next time use jsfiddle.net for code. I have created one for you: http://jsfiddle.net/mofle/sB4ma/  . The problem was that you didn't set an height for the container in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can just develop the svg code first: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_reference.asp and then develop a form to get the values.

Once you have this, then write the javascript to get the values entered on the form, using event handlers (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) and then do the appropriate calculation.